# How this centrifugal pump works in creating a vacuum?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, pumps, vacuum, vacuum-pumps

Stumbled upon [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idKXi54aA6U) video (vacuum fryer commercial)

[image]

It obviously using 2 centrifugal pump (large ones, most likely above 700 litres/min) to circulate the water inside condenser

But then, these pumps also reduce pressures inside frying chamber until vacuum condition achieved

This mesmerized me. They aren't using vacuum pump

Not to mention these pumps remain circulating vigorously throughout the frying process (2 hours)

How is this possible?

Comment: Pumps can generate a pressure below atmospheric on the suction side so that can be used.

Comment: condensers create vacuum by condensing vapor into liquid, not through vacuum pumps.